# What's the origin of Lalayet Chitta Balakam

Tags: vedanta, gita

What is the origin of this (Sanskrit?) verse; is it part of a bigger scripture?

Lalayet Chitta Balakam (*persuade with indulgence, the mind, which is a child*)

Comment: Where did you get this verse"

Comment: At 53:38 in this YouTube video https://youtu.be/jNA_1-WNDzE?t=3218 also found a Google hit at this link http://spiritual-teaching.org/ewExternalFiles/Droplets%20of%20Wisdom%20Sublime%20Complete.pdf : _Do not fall prey to despair when the mind
urges you toward worldly enjoyment. By any means,
turn your attention toward the Lord. Do not prohibit
by force a child from doing some wrong act, show
the child something more attractive and turn its
attention elsewhere._ `"Lalayet Chitta Balakam"-
persuade with indulgence the mind, which is a child.`

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give more references. It is known to be said by Vasishta Muni. Also, it is available in various versions. In general, it is accepted as a Subhashitam in sanskrit.

```
लालयेद्बालकं तावत् यावदत्र विमुग्धता । 
राजा प्रजास्विव प्रीतिं पश्चात्प्र च्छादयेत् पिता ॥
                         - हरिहरसुभाषित
```

indulging a child should be for only as long as they have innocence. After that the parents need to hide their love, like the king does for his subjects.

For a nice story on this, refer:
https://youtu.be/SOrx9bu0XlQ

Also, refer to the following links:

https://swamishantanandapurimaharaj.org/publications/Droplets-of-Wisdom-Sublime.pdf
https://archive.org/stream/gita-makarand-dusara-bhaga-by-vemuri-radhakrishna-murthy-in-hindi/Gita%20Makarand%20Dusara%20Bhaga%20By%20Vemuri%20Radhakrishna%20murthy%20In%20Hindi_djvu.txt